# Is it necessary to change my framework's bundle ID every time I submit a new app with that framework to iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I have multiple apps and i have a framework say 'X' in all of them. Do I have to set new bundle ID for my **FRAMEWORK** for every new app I use it in?

Answer (score 0):

As per i understand you are talking about third-party framework used in the Application. And in that framework there will be .plist file in that you are asking if we require to change bundle ID.

If i guess right than there is no need to change anything in that frameworks .plist file. **DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING.** Keep it as it is. Keep the default values in that .plist file & you can use it in any apps with unchanged.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: yes you can say 3rd party although i developed the APPs and the framework both myself. Anyway, actually problem occurs when I try to submit my apps to app store with my X framework with same bundle id in all apps. Due to same bundle ID of framework in every app its clashes and rejected by itunes connnect prilimiary upload!

Comment: @Divjyot that could not be the rejection reason. Please post here what the reason of rejection. Also make sure in framework plist file you can't use bundle Id of Application.